# Button action is not posting the form data to Controller in play framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, playframework

I have written a jQuery function which is opening a form in a modal dialog.

I have also added a button and when the user performs a action on the button it is calling my controller.

But the form data is not getting posted in the controller.

Please let me know if I had missed anything. Below is my code.

HTML:

```
<div id='rejectJobDialog' title='Alert: You are about to Reject a Job'>
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label>JobId</label>
      <input lang="en" id='jobId' type="text"></input>
      <br>
      <b>Why do you want to reject this?</b> 
      <textarea lang="en" id='comments' name='comments' cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
      <br>
   </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $(function() {
     $("#rejectJobDialog").dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         modal: true,
         title: 'You are about to reject a Job',
         width: 400,
         height: 400,
         closed: false,
         cache: true,
         buttons: {
             REJECT: function() {
                 $(this).dialog("close");
                 var comments = $("#comments").val();
                 if (comments === '') {
                     alert("Please Enter Comments to reject");
                 } else {
                     action: '@{WeApplicationController.rejectWeJob()}',

                     alert("We Job Rejected");
                 }
             }
         },
     });
     $("#rejectJob").click(function() {
         $("#rejectJobDialog").dialog("open");
     });
 });
```

Comment: `@{WeApplicationController.rejectWeJob()}` looks like some server side template code. What does the JavaScript that is actually sent to the browser look like?

Comment: You should run your HTML through http://validator.w3.org/nu/ - it has some issues

Comment: `action:'@{WeApplicationController.rejectWeJob()}',alert("We Job Rejected");` — I'd be very surprised if, after being processed by your server side code, this didn't result in a syntax error. Look in your browser's Developer Tools' console for errors. Use http://jshint.com/ for potentially clearer ones. … hmm, it might not result in a syntax error actually, but it doesn't make sense to have a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) called `action` there.

Comment: @Quentin  This is just a controller call  once the REJECT button is clicked.

Comment: — Define "controller call". You've tagged this `playframework` so I assume it is a Java/Scala call. That's handled server side. Do you have some other code to process it client side? Or does the server replace it with something the browser can do something useful with? Use View Source in your browser to get the real HTML/JS after it is processed by your server side code.

Comment: @Quentin Once the REJECT is clicked it needs to bind the form data to the controller , where the server will use the form data to perform some action.

Comment: What controller? Are you talking about some client side MVC framework? Or are you talking about Play, which the tag you've applied says is Java/Scala, not JavaScript.

Comment: @Quentin Am talking about play controller.

Comment: You're writing JavaScript. You can't do anything with server side code except make HTTP requests to URLs.

Comment: `action: '@{WeApplicationController.rejectWeJob()}', alert("We Job Rejected");` means "Define a label called action that marks a loop (which doesn't exist) so we can `break` or `continue` it. Then create a string and do nothing with the string. Then make an alert. It's nonsense.

Comment: If you save it does not get posted to the controller, you need to add the route and the controller code too. Including all the annotations you use in your controller..